# mysql database data import error

Tags: mysql

When I go to import data into mysql, using the wizard, from a csv file it gives me this error :

Starting...

Prepare Import...

Prepare Import done

Import data file....

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3
>   CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
>       self.func()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3
>   CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 125, in start_import
>       retval = self.module.start(self.stop)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3
>   CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 271, in start
>       ret = self.start_import()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3
>   CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 408, in
>   start_import
>       if not self.prepare_new_table():
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3
>   CE\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 237, in
>   prepare_new_table
>       self._editor.executeManagementCommand(""" CREATE TABLE %s (%s)""" % (self._table_w_prefix, ", ".join(["`%s` %s" % (col['name'],
>   col["type"]) for col in self._mapping])), 1)

DBError:

> ("Incorrect column name ''", 1166)

ERROR:

> Import data file: ("Incorrect column name ''", 1166)

Failed

Edit: I forgot to add an actual question to this, can someone help me in solving this error?

Comment: What's the question? Why is it happening? How to solve it? What?

Comment: Sorry forgot that part at the end of the post, I wish to find out how to solve it if possible?

Comment: Looks like your CSV doesn't include a column name in line 1. Can you verify it does/doesn't?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have an empty string as column name. This is not allowed as every column must have it's unique name in a table. 
If you use numeric column names you might have to escape the column_name  the same way you escape column names containing special characters.

Comment: Cheers guys i fixed it, there was an empty column in the csv that didnt have a title i forgot to remove a note i made on the side.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with the same error. The solution is quite simple though.

In the .csv file from which you were trying to import data from, if you look closely the field names and rows are in order such as:

```
;"created_at";"updated_at";"country_code";"mobile_number";"site_context";"country";"user_id";"uuid"
1;1547471922220;1547471922220;"91";"9711843454";"rexmonster";"IN";0;""
2;1547471959995;1547471959995;"91";"971184";"rexmonster";"IN";0;""
```

Here, the first col. name is null which is creating the error.
All you need to do is just provide any column name at that place
e.g.:

```
"SerialNum";"created_at";"updated_at";"country_code";"mobile_number";"site_context";"country";"user_id";"uuid"
1;1547471922220;1547471922220;"91";"9711843454";"rexmonster";"IN";0;""
2;1547471959995;1547471959995;"91";"971184";"rexmonster";"IN";0;""
```

Boom you are done. 
The import will work smooth now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and my problem was that there were spaces in the headers of my csv file.  Simply open the csv with a text editor, and remove the spaces.